# Is there any difference in putting the logging statement in a module level vs in a class level?

Tags: python, logging

**module1.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__main__)
class MyClass()
    def __init__(self):
        LOGGER.info('test')
```

Versus

**module2.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
class MyClass()
    def __init__(self):
        self.LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__main__)
        self.LOGGER.info('test')
```

Seems to me like module2.py will give some unpredictable outcome when imported by other modules.
I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

`logging.getLogger()` returns a singleton (per given name); there's no difference in storing it as a module global or as an instance attribute. Your code is referencing the same object in both cases.

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects):

> Multiple calls to `getLogger()` with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object.

and from the [`logging.getLogger()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) itself:

> All calls to this function with a given name return the same logger instance. This means that logger instances never need to be passed between different parts of an application.

Comment: hmmm ..... Your answer make sense. And that's what i thought as well, but seems like I'm still seeing strange output. One question ...... Does it matter (or does it make any difference) if we were to do import logging, and then logging.getLogger(__name__)  versus  from logging import getLogger, and then getLogger(__name__) ?

Comment: No, none whatsoever. It's still the same function you are referencing.